# React: how to use setState and render component when prop changes

Tags: reactjs, render

This app is supposed to filter words by a specific input. I want to call a function with `setState()` when rendering a component and technically it's working but there is warning in the console.

> Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.

I guess that this is because I'm calling the function in the render function which I shouldn't, but what should I do instead?

```
class UsersList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      allUsers: ["Michał", "Ania", "Kasia", "Tomek", "Hubert", "Jan", "Martyna", "Rafał", "Bartłomiej"],
      filteredUsers: [],
      input: null
    }
  }

  filter() {
    if (this.state.input !== this.props.inputValue) {
      const filtered = this.state.allUsers.filter(user => user.toLowerCase().includes(this.props.inputValue));
      this.setState({
        filteredUsers: filtered.map(user => <li key={user}>{user}</li>),
        input: this.props.inputValue
      })
    }

    return this.state.filteredUsers;
  }

  render() {
    this.filter()
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.filteredUsers}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {input: ""};
    this.handleInput = this.handleInput.bind(this);
  }

  handleInput(e) {
    this.setState({input: e.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleInput} type="search"/>
        <UsersList inputValue={this.state.input} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: update in event handlers or other lifecycles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is caused by changes being made to your component's state during rendering.

You should avoid setting component state directly during a components `render()` function (this is happening when you call `filter()` during your component's `render()` function).

Instead, consider updating the `state` of your component only as needed (ie when the `inputValue` prop changes). The recommended way to update `state` when `prop` values change is via the [`getDerivedStateFromProps()`](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#new-lifecycle-getderivedstatefromprops) component life cycle hook.

Here's an example of how you could make use of this hook for your component:

```
class UsersList extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            allUsers: ["Michał", "Ania", "Kasia", "Tomek", 
                       "Hubert", "Jan", "Martyna", "Rafał",
                       "Bartłomiej"],
            filteredUsers: [],
            input: null
        }
    }

    /* Add this life cycle hook, it replaces filter(). Props are updated/incoming 
       props, state is current state of component instance */
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {

        // The condition for prop changes that trigger an update
        if(state.input !== props.inputValue) {

            const filtered = state.allUsers.filter(user => user.toLowerCase().includes(props.inputValue));

            /* Return the new state object seeing props triggered an update */
            return {
                allUsers: state.allUsers
                filteredUsers: filtered.map(user => <li key={user}>{user}</li>),
                input: props.inputValue
            }
        }

        /* No update needed */
        return null;
    }

    render() {

        return (<ul>{this.state.filteredUsers}</ul>)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming up as it could create an endless loop inside the component. As `render` method is executed whenever the state is updated and your function `this.filter` is doing a state update. Now as the state updates, your render method triggers the function again.

Best way to do that would be in `lifecycle methods` or maintain the uses in the `App` and make `UserList` a dumb component by always passing the list of filtered users for it to display.